# How to stub out express after you require it with jasmine?

Tags: node.js, express, jasmine, jasmine-node

I'm trying to get the code below under test when occurred to me that I already included express at the top of this file. Can you some how monkey patch the express object after it's already loaded?

```
var express = require('express')

Helper = (function() {                                                                           

  var HelperObject = function(params) {
    this.directories = params.directories;
  };

  HelperObject.prototype.addStaticPath = function(app) {
    for(i = 0; i < this.directories.length; i++) {                                               
      var static = express.static('/public');
      app.use(static);
    }
  };

  return HelperObject;
})();
```

Comment: for now I've decided to pass in both express and app so I can test the interaction in true isolation. That said, I'd still like to know if anyone has done what I described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you create a node module the required modul is bound in the closure of the module and you can't start spying on it cause it isn't visible in your test.

There is [Gently](https://github.com/felixge/node-gently#gentlyhijackrealrequire) where you can override require but it will sprinkle your code with boilerplate test related code.

From the docs:

> Returns a new require functions that catches a reference to all
> required modules into gently.hijacked.
>
> To use this function, include a line like this in your 'my-module.js'.

```
if (global.GENTLY) require = GENTLY.hijack(require);

var sys = require('sys');
exports.hello = function() {
  sys.log('world');
};
```

> Now you can write a test for the module above:

```
var gently = global.GENTLY = new (require('gently'))
  , myModule = require('./my-module');

gently.expect(gently.hijacked.sys, 'log', function(str) {
  assert.equal(str, 'world');
});

myModule.hello();
```